# XSLT2.0 transformation generating tags in multiple lines

Tags: xslt-2.0

i am getting the following output after running an xslt2.0 transformation.

```
<TAG mode="w"
           name="x"
           references="x"
           size="5005"
           type="string"/>
```

I would like this to be dumped in a single line itself.

```
<TAG mode="w" name="x" references="x" size="5005" type="string"/>
```

Code which breaks the line is:

```
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" byte-order-mark="no" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template name="agt:var1_function1">
    <xsl:param name="par0" as="node()"/>
    <TAG>
        <xsl:sequence select="($par0/@node(), $par0/node())"/>
    </TAG>
</xsl:template>
```

Can you please suggest me what i am doing wrong here and why this line is breaking into multiple lines?

Best Regards
Rajesh

Comment: You forgot to post the wrong output.

Comment: Thanks Oscar. Indentation was wrong.

Comment: Your question is duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922882/xsl-remove-a-line-break-from-text

Answer (score 1):

If your XSLT processor is Saxon 9 then it has a serialization option http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/html/extensions/output-extras/line-length.html you can set to define a line length at which attributes should be put on a new line. As you don't want line breaks I would use a very high value e.g.

```
<xsl:output xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/" saxon:line-length="5000"/>
```

Comment: Thanks Martin, I tried the serialization option but still the same result. I am running the xslt from command line java -jar saxon9he input.xml transform.xslt -o:output.xml do i need to change any thing in the command

Comment: @user3355730, when I try with Saxon 9.5 HE then I get an error saying "Transformation failed: Requested feature (custom serialization {http://saxon.sf.net/}line-length) requires Saxon-PE" so I am afraid that option is not supported for HE. On the other hand I don't understand why you didn't get the same error. With Saxon 9.5 PE I see that `saxon:line-length` works as long as the `xsl:output indent="yes"` is set as well.